# What error handling should be used in VBNET

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, error-handling, save

THIS IS MY CODE FOR SAVE BTN

```
 Private Sub SaveBtn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As 
 System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn2.Click
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter


    Dim con As String = "Data Source = HCA-ISD03\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = QMS_HCA; User ID=qs; Password=ZAQ!2wsx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(con)

    conn.Open()

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "spSaveAddNewAlerts"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure


    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MESSAGE", Message.Text)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DCREATED", DateTimePicker1.Value)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATEDBY", Createdby.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()





    If Message.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Message cannot be empty, fill in before proceeding", _
                        "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Message.Focus()


    Else
        MessageBox.Show("Application Restarting..", _
                        "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Message.Focus()
        Application.Restart()

        conn.Close()

    End If

    MsgBox("Saved, Updating Database..")
    Application.Restart()


End Sub
```

How can I interrupt the data to be saved in database. Even if I have message error and I've closed my connection. Still the data goes to the database. Please help. Thank you!

Comment: You're executing your query before you check the validity of your data. Check the validity first, for example using `IF`s, and then put run the query in afterwards, for example in your `ELSE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put your validations before the stored procedure call and just return out of the click handler if you have a validation error?

```
Private Sub SaveBtn2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn2.Click

    'Check this first, before running the stored procedure!
    If Message.Text = "" Then

        MessageBox.Show("Message cannot be empty, fill in before proceeding",
                    "User Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Message.Focus()
        Return 'Exit the method!
    End If

    Dim dt As New DataTable
    Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter

    Dim con As String = "Data Source = HCA-ISD03\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = QMS_HCA; User ID=qs; Password=ZAQ!2wsx; MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
    Dim conn As New SqlConnection(con)

    conn.Open()

    cmd.Connection = conn
    cmd.CommandText = "spSaveAddNewAlerts"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MESSAGE", Message.Text)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DCREATED", DateTimePicker1.Value)

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CREATEDBY", Createdby.Text)

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

    conn.Close()

    MsgBox("Saved, Updating Database..")
    Application.Restart()
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Big help. Problem Solved.